# Binary Tree Creation

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am attempting to create a binary tree from an input of 0's and 1's. For example if the input is 11010010 then the tree that is outputted would have 1 as the root. 2 would be the left child of 1 and 4 would be the right child. 2 would have a right child and it would be 3. That is the end of the tree. As the tree is traversed in preorder, the numbers 1-n (n being the number of 1's in the input) are assigned to the nodes that are visited. A 1 means that the root has children. For example the first 1 means that the root is visited and a 1 is placed as the root. The second 1 means that the root has a left child and a 2 is placed there. The 0 after that means it does not have a left child. The next 1 means that it does have a right child and the 3 is placed there, etc. I am confused on how this tree is created. I understand traversing a tree after it has been created but not how to create a tree by traversing it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package tree;

import java.io.*;

public class BinaryTree<ArrayList> implements Serializable
{   
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected static class Node<ArrayList> implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected int data;
    protected Node<ArrayList> left;
    protected Node<ArrayList> right;

    public Node(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }

    public boolean isLeft() 
    {
        return (left == null);
    }
}

protected Node<ArrayList> root;;

public BinaryTree(int x)
{
    Node<ArrayList> node = new Node<ArrayList>(x);
    this.root = node;
}

public boolean isLeft()
{
    return(root.left == null);
}

public void addLeft(int m, BinaryTree.Node<ArrayList> node)
{
    root = new Node<ArrayList>(m);
    node.left = root;
}   

 public void preorder(Node<ArrayList> temp)  
 {  
      if (temp!=null)  
      {  
           System.out.println(temp.data);  
           preorder(temp.left);  
           preorder(temp.right);  
      }  
      else  
           return;  
 }
```

}

Comment: Can you format it to be more readable.

Comment: @Jayamohan I'm sorry I do not know what you mean. Format the question?

Comment: What is your question? Also have you tried anything? I suggest that you provide at least a little bit of code to help illustrate what you are asking about.

Comment: @Code-Guru I added code and really my question is how to create a binary tree in preorder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're constructing a tree in a default, breadth-first manner, assigning values to each node based off of what the string says.

If it helps, first turn the string into an `ArrayList<int>` of values to put in nodes - For example, `11010010` would become `{1, 2, 4, 7}`, the indices of each set 1 in the string.

Now, we have to construct the tree - but we'll always construct the tree in the exact same way, called breadth first because you fill shallow levels completely before going deep. We make a node, then tell it 'make your left node, then make your right node, then tell your left node to do this, then tell your right node to do this'. (This is as opposed to depth first, where you make your left node, tell your left node to make nodes, then make your right node and tell your right node to make nodes)

So you'd have a recursive method something like this pseudocode:

```
void continueTree(ArrayList<int> numbers)
{
    if (numbers.count() == 0) return;
    this.left = new Node(numbers.get(0));
    numbers.remove(0);
    if (numbers.count() == 0) return;
    this.right = new Node(numbers.get(0));
    numbers.remove(0);
    this.left.continueTree(numbers);
    this.right.continueTree(numbers);
}
```